# How to change FxCop language?

Tags: internationalization, fxcop

Is it possible to change the language of the FxCop dictionary to something other than English?
How can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

FxCop comes with its own dictionary. You can add custom dictionaries that have words from any language.

This site shows how to add a custom dictionary:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/fxcop/archive/2007/08/20/new-for-visual-studio-2008-custom-dictionaries.aspx

This site mentions that FxCop has some support for other languages.

- http://davesbox.com/archive/2008/06/08/fxcop-now-ships-with-the-spell-checker-libraries.aspx

> You can tell FxCop to use non-American varieties by choose Project -> Options -> Spelling & Analysis and changing the Spelling language drop-down. It will also default to the user's default culture, so if your locale is set to Australia, then the language will default to English (Australia).

Comment: Adding all the words from a language into a dictionary seems way too impractical, and Fx-Cop has in-built support only for English.

Comment: If it's not possible then it's not possible.